# Android: design does not same for all devices

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.elektro.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/radial_background" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/brutus_blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_open1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/open" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wave1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark" />
```

This is my layout xml code when I run it by using different devices, the design of layout looks different for each devices.For example, the button does not appear the same region.How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing tag. Close `RelativeLayout` tag and try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.elektro.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/radial_background" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/brutus_blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_open1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/open" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wave1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark" />
```